# Ignore Bash Trace in expect

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I am try to write regression tests using expect for an interactive bash script.

So far everything works Ok. I spawn the process with the correct arguments, and then `send`/`expect`.

I would like, during tests, to enable tracing in the bash script, using the `set -x` command. However, when doing so, the bash trace output messes with expect.

I would like expect to ignore those lines when performing matching but still output them on either stdout or stderr.

Apperently, there is so way to treat stderr and stdout independently.

I have already tried a few thing using `expect_before` and `expect_background`, but none having given me good results.

Any thoughts ?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe redirect the shell's stderr to a file and print it afterwards?  Notice also the redirection facility of `exec`.

Comment: `exec` does not allow interacting with the process as `spawn` does, from what I've understood. An alternative solution would be spawning a `bash` process to perform the redirection, but I'd prefer a cleaner way.

Comment: Oh, I mean the shell's `exec` command.

Answer (score 0):

If the output (I mean non-trace output) from your `bash` script if well-defined, you can simply ignore the trace output when using `expect` command. For example, if your script shows:

```
+ echo 'Password:'
Password:
```

you can use regexp mode of `expect`:

```
expect -re '^Password:'
```

That would ignore the trace output but match the password prompt. Granted, your match rules should be very tight to not match any undesirable output.